# Mongodb field value as another field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I just want to get filed value where field is value of another filed.
ex: below  I want to get valueOf("Brand")="Toshiba" where "Brand" is value of field mappingData.brand

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b988de0be317251"),
        "Part number" : "PS460E-04NVX-NL",
        "Brand" : "Toshiba",
        "Quality" : "XYZ",
        "Category" : "notebooks",
        "Model Name" : "Satellite Pro 4600 PIII900",
        "EAN" : "",
        "Market Presence" : "N",
        "Family" : "",
        "Title" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII900",
        "mapping" : {
                "brand" : "Brand",
                "title" : "Title"               
        }
}
```

I am trying this following way but it is returning undefined.

```
db.products.find().limit( 5 ).forEach(function(myDoc) { 
 var b=myDoc.mappingData.brand;
    print(myDoc.$$b);

})
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)** to access the property of an object. In your case, this would be

```
db.products.find().limit(5).forEach(function(myDoc) { 
    var brand = myDoc.mappingData.brand,
        brandVal = myDoc[brand];
    print(brandVal);
})
```

Comment: Thanks chridam. It helped me alot.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAnugula No worries, glad to help :)